# How to put a TCP socket in waiting state

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

In my application, I use a System.Threading.Timer that ticks after every 3 seconds, and establish a tcp socket connection to the server, and send an image file to the server. Currently on every timer tick event, I establish a TCP connection with the server and then send the data.

My question is, is it possible that I make the connection only once and send file on the timer tick, if yes, then how can I put the server on the waiting state, to wait for new data to arrive.

Here is my server side code snippet..

```
            client = listeningSocket.Accept();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                   try
                   {
                      //code to receive client data.

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                }
            }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `client.Receive(....)`  or use the `client.GetStream()` for the  `NetworkStream` for `await ReadAsync()`

Comment: I know this. I mean when no data is coming from client, how can I put the server on waiting state, to wait for new data to arrive, instead of disconnecting the socket and connecting again.

Comment: `client.Receive()` is blocking. Which means that it will wait until data is received. You need to receive to know there is nothing coming. It is the waiting state. Do not use anything like DataAvailable etc...